# Tasks and Threads don't run within static constructors in Linqpad

Tags: c#, linqpad, static-constructor

This code waits indefinitely on the `t.Wait()` line.

```
void Main()
{
    Foo.Bar();
}

public static class Foo
{
    static Foo()
    {
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => 1);
        t.Wait();
        "Done".Dump();
    }

    public static void Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

I would expect the task to run and finish immediately.  Any thoughts as to why?  This doesn't seem to happen in instance constructors. v4.42.01

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "`StartNew`-and-`Wait`" part of your code works as expected (`t.Result` will be `1`), if you put it into the `Main` or into the `Bar` method. It doesn't stop `Wait`-ing only if you put it into the static constructor, because "[any operation that blocks the current thread in a static constructor potentially risks a deadlock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/05/03/10159682.aspx)".

In order to prevent executing static ctors multiple times concurrently, the CLR executes them under a lock. Here you try to call an anonymous method of Foo, and wait for it to finish, from the static ctor of Foo, which causes a deadlock.

Related SO pages: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465961/potential-pitfalls-with-static-constructors-in-c-sharp), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594975/why-will-an-empty-net-task-not-complete-if-started-and-waited-for-from-a-static)